# Combinatorics - counting words with 3 letter substring.

Tags: combinatorics

We have multiset of letters. Each letter have to be used only once. And we have 3 letter word. How much words we can create with letters from multiset containing our 3 letter word?

-Each letter have to be used once.

-We are looking for three letter subword in word created with letters from multiset.

-Word AABCA contains subword ABA here **A**A**B**C**A**

For example:
Multiset: {A, A, B, C A} and word ABA

Correct strings:

ABACA

ABCAA

AABCA

AABAC

ACBAA
...

Comment: At first glance, this won't have a nice closed formula for the general case (with a lot of repetitions of letters).

Comment: @yo' Edited question.

Comment: $ABCAA$ doesn't contain the string $ABA$, nor does $AABCA$...what's the rule again?

Comment: We are looking for subword in word.

Comment: But it doesn't have to be consecutive?  I, for one, would interpret "subword" as "consecutive subword".

Comment: Ohh yea, I'm sorry. It doesn't have to be consecutive.

Comment: For example word AABCA contains word ABA here **A**A**B**C**A**

Comment: I suggest editing the post to specify that...I think most (if not all) readers will interpret it the way I did.